# How to deal with x/|x| in an equation?

Tags: optimization, absolute-value

How do I solve the following for x?

$$ 0 = x-b+\lambda\frac{x}{|x|} $$

I'm trying to minimize $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x-b)^2 + \lambda|x|$$ I took the derivative and now I'm trying to set it to $0$ and solve. It's a pen-and-paper question so I can't turn it into a quadratic program and feed it into a solver. I think the solution is something like $x = b \pm \lambda$ but I can't quite get there.

Comment: Break into cases with the values $\pm 1$, depending on the sign of $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use definition $$|x| =\begin{cases}x ,\ \  \  \text{if}\ \  x \geq 0 \\ -x ,\text{if}\ \ \  x < 0\end{cases}$$

Then you'll have $$\frac{x}{|x|} =\begin{cases}1 ,\ \  \  \text{if}\ \  x >0 \\ -1 ,\text{if}\ \ \  x < 0\end{cases} $$

Comment: for $x=0$ is the quotient $\frac{x}{|x|}$ undefined

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well remembered, I just copied from definition above.